# Number of records in index

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an elasticsearch query method, but it only yields me 10 records of an index --- does someone know how I can get all the records that I have?

```
 var consultaPlazaCobro = elasticClient.Search<Entity.PlazaCobroELK>(s => s
           .Index("plazacobro")
           .Type("logs")
           .Query(q => q.QueryString(qs => qs.Query("*"))));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have less than 10000 documents, you can use the `.Size()` method call:

```
 var consultaPlazaCobro = elasticClient.Search<Entity.PlazaCobroELK>(s => s
       .Size(10000)
       .Index("plazacobro")
       .Type("logs")
       .Query(q => q.QueryString(qs => qs.Query("*"))));
```

Otherwise you need to resort to using a [Scroll request](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net/blob/21ec77980f92974ce0ca83aa6eb43fdb00260550/src/Nest/Search/Scroll/Scroll/ScrollRequest.cs)

Comment: Thanks man
If I have 2 index that were 2 tables in sql, can a query be made with the id?

Comment: Not sure I understand

Comment: My question is if I have 2 index can perform an inner to make a query and as it would be in c # you will have some example